WSO2 APIM 4.3.0 start up failure with JDK 17
I have downloaded WSO2 APIM 4.3.0 from wso2 github
WSO2 APIM: 4.3.0
Java: JDK 17.0.12
OS: Windows 11
And followed pre requisites mentioned in same page.

Installed JDK Version 17.
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is set
Extracted the downloaded zip file and started api-manager.bat

While starting server below ERROR found :
ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/application-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/application-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.

ERROR LOGS:
[2024-09-24 22:36:46,416]  INFO - QpidServiceComponent Activating Andes Message Broker Engine...
[Broker] BRK-1001 : Startup : Version: 0.11 Build: 90784:90849
[Broker] MNG-1001 : Startup
[Broker] MNG-1004 : Ready : Using the platform JMX Agent
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,370]  INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,382]  INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672
[Broker] BRK-1004 : Qpid Broker Ready
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,415]  INFO - QpidServiceComponent AMQP Host Address : 0.0.0.0 Port : 5672
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,415]  INFO - QpidServiceComponent Successfully connected to AMQP server on port 5672
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,416]  INFO - QpidServiceComponent WSO2 Message Broker is started.
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,661]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiver Started Binary SSL Transport on port : 9711
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,663]  INFO - BinaryDataReceiver Started Binary TCP Transport on port : 9611
[2024-09-24 22:36:47,990]  INFO - ThriftServerStartupObserver  Thrift Data Receiver is disabled.
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,079]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Starting Pass-through HTTP Listener...
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,102]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8280
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,103]  INFO - PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener Starting Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,128]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through HTTPS Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8243
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,229]  INFO - certificate Connector [https-jsse-nio-9443], TLS virtual host [_default_], certificate type [UNDEFINED] configured from keystore [F:\WSO2_Learning\wso2am-4.3.0\wso2am-4.3.0\bin\../repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks] using alias [wso2carbon] with trust store [F:\WSO2_Learning\wso2am-4.3.0\wso2am-4.3.0\bin\../repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks]
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,327]  INFO - TaskServiceImpl Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,371]  INFO - RegistryEventingServiceComponent Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,512]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,703]  WARN - CorrelationConfigManager Failed retrieving correlation configs. Retrying after 2 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:36:48,703]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 4 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:36:49,141] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/application-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/application-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:36:49,141] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/subscription-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/subscription-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:36:49,141] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/api-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/api-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:36:49,141] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/application-key-mappings from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/application-key-mappings. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:36:49,141] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/applications from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/applications. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:36:49,141] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/apis from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/apis. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:36:49,142] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/subscriptions from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/subscriptions. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 1 in 15 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:36:50,721]  WARN - CorrelationConfigManager Failed retrieving correlation configs. Retrying after 4 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:36:52,721]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 16 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:36:54,737]  WARN - CorrelationConfigManager Failed retrieving correlation configs. Retrying after 8 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:37:02,753]  WARN - CorrelationConfigManager Failed retrieving correlation configs. Retrying after 16 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:37:04,157] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/subscriptions from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/subscriptions. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 2 in 30 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:04,157] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/application-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/application-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 2 in 30 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:04,158] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/application-key-mappings from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/application-key-mappings. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 2 in 30 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:04,158] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/subscription-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/subscription-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 2 in 30 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:04,158] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/applications from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/applications. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 2 in 30 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:04,159] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/api-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/api-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 2 in 30 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:04,160] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/apis from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/apis. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 2 in 30 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:08,734]  WARN - KeyManagerConfigurationDataRetriever Failed retrieving Key Manager Configurations from remote endpoint. Retrying after 64 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:37:18,763]  WARN - CorrelationConfigManager Failed retrieving correlation configs. Retrying after 32 seconds...
[2024-09-24 22:37:34,179] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/applications from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/applications. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 3 in 60 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:34,181] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/subscription-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/subscription-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 3 in 60 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:34,182] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/application-key-mappings from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/application-key-mappings. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 3 in 60 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:34,183] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/apis from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/apis. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 3 in 60 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:34,185] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/api-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/api-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 3 in 60 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:34,186] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/subscriptions from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/subscriptions. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 3 in 60 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:34,186] ERROR - APIUtil Failed to retrieve /internal/data/v1/application-policies from remote endpoint: Error while retrieving /internal/data/v1/application-policies. Received response with status code 404. Retry attempt 3 in 60 seconds.
[2024-09-24 22:37:50,786]  WARN - CorrelationConfigManager Failed retrieving correlation configs. Retrying after 64 seconds...

I tried restarting wso2 apim server couple of times and added host entry as well mentioned like here
Is there any product installation or compatibility issue with JDK 17?

What is the database you are using?

It seems like this error is caused by a database error. If you are using a different database please configure it in the deployment.toml file inside the APIM 4.3.0 pack.
[database.apim]
type = "mysql" # or your database type
url = "jdbc:mysql://<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>"
username = "<db_user>"
password = "<db_password>"

